# How to stop a deployed docker stack?

Tags: docker, docker-stack

I just completed the [beginners Docker tutorials](https://github.com/docker/labs/blob/master/beginner/chapters/votingapp.md) and would like to know how to clean up.

I deployed a stack and with a few different service using the below command:

```
docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-stack.yml vote
```

Is there away to stop all the containers associated with this stack, or do I have to stop them individually?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can remove a stack with:

```
docker stack rm vote
```

At present, this is still a detached operation that will take time to run in the background.

---

If for some reason you still want the stack and service definitions, you can scale the "replicated" services down to 0 replicas, and "global" services you can add a constraint that doesn't match any node.

```
docker service update --replicas 0 $service_name
docker service update --constraint-add node.labels.no_such_node=true $service_name
```

Comment: I just wanted to mention that it can take a while (10-15 seconds) for all of the containers to stop. I thought that `docker stack rm` wasn't cleaning everything up, which is why I found this SO question.

Comment: Isn't `docker stack rm` also deleting the containers? Shouldn't there be a command to just stop them when needed?

Comment: Swarm mode orchestration has the objective to make the current state match your target definition. So "stop all the containers" brings your current state out of the target state goal and swarm will try to correct that. You could do this by changing your target, but that needs to be done per service.

Comment: Following worked for me "global" deployments, Windows Docker Swarm
`docker service update --constraint-add no_such_node==true $service_name`